import osgeo: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _gdal
I'm loading osgeo in a conda python environment. Initially I installed again gdal and libgdal according to this post and seems to work. I'm using the python located at: C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\r-miniconda\\envs\\ENVNAME\\python.exe
Python 3.9.19 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 20 2024, 12:38:46) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

When I run import osgeo I got it running when doing it on python from Anaconda PowerShell Prompt (miniconda3) found at  %windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\Admin\miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\Admin\miniconda3
But got an error when running on the same python launched on Windows Power shell and Anaconda prompt (miniconda 3). I'm located in the same folder in the three cases
Anaconda Powershell Prompt (miniconda3): %windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command "& 'C:\Users\Admin\miniconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\Users\Admin\miniconda3'
Windows PowerShell: %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
How can I import osgeo on the same Python but from different consoles?
Here the error I got:
(base) C:\Users\Admin>C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\r-miniconda\\envs\\ENVNAME/python.exe
Python 3.9.19 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 20 2024, 12:38:46) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import osgeo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\ENVNAME\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 30, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\ENVNAME\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 565, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1173, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _gdal: Not found specific proccess

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\ENVNAME\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\ENVNAME\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 32, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_gdal')
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\ENVNAME\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _gdal: Not found specific process
>>>

Also, when getting import sys; sys.path, I got the same response in the three consoles:
['', 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\r-miniconda\\envs\\cola\\python39.zip',
'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\r-miniconda\\envs\\cola\\DLLs', 
'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\r-miniconda\\envs\\cola\\lib', 
'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\r-miniconda\\envs\\cola', 
'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\r-miniconda\\envs\\cola\\lib\\site-packages']


At first sight, it looks like you are not activating the environment you installed gdal in first. You should first call conda activate ENVNAME.
